# Kafka - sending the reply exactly to the sender

Tags: apache-kafka, distributed-system

I need some guidance wrt Kafka and Distributed Systems

I have created a distributed system using Kafka. Let us assume the following architecture and data flow

[image: architecture-diasgram]

1. The load balancer sends the request to the Service Containers
2. The Service containers send the message to the Kafka Worker Queue and maintains a Set to maintain the messages it has sent to the Kafka
3. A single GPU worker gets the message and performs work accordingly and writes the answer to the answer queue. The request ID is in the answer.
4. All the services get the Answer and they check if the request ID of the answer belongs to the Set. If no, they drop the message. Otherwise they send the reply to the client.

My questions are following

1. In this architecture the answer is recieved by all the services and they get very less useful messages for them. How to improve it so that ONLY the service sending the message gets the answer.
2. How can I do this in a autoscaling enviornment where the number of service nodes/containers/pods is dynamic?

Comment: "ONLY the service sending the message gets the answer". Have you looked at Spring-kafka ReplyingKafkaTemplate? Otherwise, it's bad practice to couple your producer and consumer

Comment: I would say that in distributed systems you don't want that type of coupling. You normally cannot assume that the instance that wrote the message into the queue is still running when the answer is put in the queue. The instance could be scaled down or failed. You would also lose the exactly-once character. And maybe your response-message is never processed.
Why do you need the same instance to process the answer? Can you transform your architecture to state-free/session-free processing?

Comment: I can take the state outside the services on a REDIS instance while the GPUs directly write the answers to the REDIS.  That will make it stateless, but then the instances will have to poll for the requests they have created as the client is having connections with the service instances and reply needs to be sent by that service instance.

Is there any other way of making it stateless where we can remove the binding that the client has a connection with the service instance?

Comment: You could return something like a processingID on the initial request and then the client can poll another endpoint to check if the processing is already finished.
Otherwise you could replace your Kafka with a sort of synchronous API as you want a synchronous API to the client. Then you don't have the overhead of synchronising your asynchronous processing in the background.